# Issue with Blender export to Unreal

Tags: animation

I seem to be having an issue importing an FBX from Blender to Unreal 4, as you can see from the images below. I'm not sure what is going on here. I've tried limiting bone influence, Normalizing weights, applying location, rotation, and scale. I am lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I'll upload the .blend if someone can tell me how to do it.

[image: Mesh in Blender]

[image: Mesh in Unreal]

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com for .blend upload. As for your problem, did you check non-manifold faces with Ctrl-Alt-Shift-m?